# R: How to merge non-aligned data frames based on column values

Tags: r

I have the following R program where **df.1 and df.2 have a different number of rows and ItemIndex is unique in each data frame**:

```
df.1 = data.frame(ItemName = ItemNameVector, ItemIndex = ItemIndexVector)
df.1.len = length(df$ItemName)

df.2 = data.frame(ItemIndex = ItemIndexVector2)

ret = vector(length = df.1.ret)
for( i in 1:df.1.len ) {
  index = df.1[i, "ItemIndex"]
  ret[i] = df.2[df.1$ItemIndex == index, "ItemName"]
}
```

In other words I want to find all df.1 ItemName values where df.1 ItemIndex match df.2 ItemIndex. ItemIndex values are unique, but they are not the same in df.1 and df.2.

I think there is something with merge(), but I wasn't able to make it work for selective cases based on the value of each field.

What is the simplest way to do this in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is answer to your question (your code returns data from df.2 not df.1).

```
subset(df.1, ItemIndex %in% df.2$ItemIndex, select=ItemName)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is untested, since your example is not reproducible, but I think you may be looking for `match` (ironically enough):

```
ret <- df.2$ItemName[match(df.1$ItemIndex, df.2$ItemIndex)]
```

Note that `match` returns the position of the *first* match, so this is using your assumption of uniqueness of ItemIndex.

Comment: Thanks. Precisely what I was looking for.